# What is the energy consumption of incandescent bulb as compared to LEDs and CFL bulbs?

Tags: power, light, energy, electricity

I read this on website "The electricity used over the lifetime of a single incandescent bulb costs 5 to 10 times the original purchase price of the bulb itself"
What does it mean? if the bulb is of 100 Rs then it means it will consume power of 500 to 1000 Rs in lifetime? and how long is this life? It doesn't make sense to me.
Website: http://eartheasy.com/live_energyeff_lighting.htm

Comment: Google it or calculate it. It has nothing to do with electronic design.

Comment: You link had another link to answer your question.   http://eartheasy.com/live_led_bulbs_comparison.html  Good Engineers often pay more attention to details and find answers like this trival.  If you wish to become one, it takes lots of practice with attention to details.

Comment: What unit is "R" for energy? And the useful point is about watts per lumen, not anything per lifetime

Comment: @PlasmaHH it's not R. It's Rs that means rupees.  Pakistani currency

Comment: How on earth is that any meaningful unit of power (consumption)?

Comment: @PlasmaHH I am talking about power consumption in terms of money

Comment: Here it is all about engineering, money is a useless value in power consumption

Comment: This question has no meaning without considering the life span of each category of bulb. *That* should be the question. VTC unless OP edits the question to be more rational.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do not get your electricity for free it means you pay so much a month to power that light bulb.

If the light bulb lasts and average of 5 or 10 years, that cost adds up to be more than the bulb cost in the first place.

It's fairly meaningless number though, and is more a marketing ploy to convince you the more efficient bulbs are worth the extra money to buy them up front.

Comment: Yes, an incandescend cost a few cents while other bulbs cost 10x more. So if it cost you in electricity the same (1x) as the cost of the expensive bulb, the expensive bulb is as bad as the cheap one because at the end of year you paid the same.